# Multiple process django form

Tags: python, django-forms

Trying to create a convert the following bootstrap form to django form 
https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG?editors=1010 using one view

Am done with the fisrt part of getting the data and saving them into django session .. how to i redirect to the second part without using js or ajax

```
if rf.is_valid():
    logger.debug("the form is valid ")
    email = rf.cleaned_data.get("email")
    first = rf.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
    last = rf.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
    password = rf.cleaned_data.get("password")
    phone = rf.cleaned_data.get("phone")
    logger.info("trying to register")
    try:
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, password, phone, first)
        user.username = user.email
        #user.first_name = first
        user.last_name = last
        #user.phone = phone
        if original_referrer:
            user.original_referrer = original_referrer
        request.session['user_details'] = {
            "email": rf.cleaned_data["email"],
            "first": rf.cleaned_data["first_name"],
            "last": rf.cleaned_data["last_name"],
            "password": rf.cleaned_data["password"],
            "phone": rf.cleaned_data["phone"],

        }
        logger.debug(request.session['user_details'])
        is_successed=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming since you saved the data into a session you want to redirect to another view and access that session data. You can do it like this

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect

if rf.is_valid():
    ...
    # Replace with your url or use the reverse function for a named url
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/the/next/view/')
```

then in your next view

```
def step2_view(request):
    user_details = request.session['user_details']
```

You could also have a look at the wizard forms from the django-formtools library, which make some of this easier imo https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html